# Onchange select option display result on another select option

Tags: javascript, php

I have created the code below to perform function onchange when value on select is selected.

I am  hoping to see the second select option change when the first select option is selected .

Below is the first select option that triggers the change to second select option when onchange.

```
<div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-3 control-label">
                <label for="spacing"><?php echo ('Spacing'); ?><span class="star">&nbsp;*</span></label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-7">
                <select name="spacing" id="spacing" class="required" onchange="showPagesDiv(this.value);
                caltotal(this);">
                <option value="Double Spaced">Double Spaced</option>
                <option value="Single Spaced">Single Spaced</option>
            </select>
        </div>
```

Below is the second select option that changes as a result of the first select option on change

```
<div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-3 control-label">
            <label for="no_of_pages1">No of Pages or words<span class="star">&nbsp;*</span></label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-7">

            <div id="single" style="display: none;">
                <select name="no_of_pages1" id="no_of_pages1" onchange="caltotal()">
                      <?php
                    $query = $conn->query("SELECT  * FROM cww_avid_pages_words");
                     while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                        if ($row['idpw'] == $post['no_of_pages']) {
                       echo '<option selected="selected" id="' . $row['idpw'] . 'nop" value="' . $row['idpw'] . '" title="' . $row['amount_added'] . '"> ' . $row['pages'] . ' Page(s) / ' . $row['words'] . ' Words</option>';
                    } else{
                         echo '<option selected="selected" id="' . $row['idpw'] . 'nop" value="' . $row['idpw'] . '" title="' . $row['amount_added'] . '"> ' . $row['pages'] . ' Page(s) / ' . $row['words'] . ' Words</option>';
                    }
                }
                    ?>

                </select>
            </div>
            <div id="double" >
                <select name="no_of_pages2" id="no_of_pages2" onchange="caltotal()">
                    <?php
                    $query = $conn->query("SELECT  * FROM cww_avid_pages_words");
                     while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                        if ($row['idpw'] == $post['no_of_pages']) {
                        echo '<option selected="selected" id="' . $row['idpw'] . 'nop" value="' . $row['idpw'] . '" title="' . $row['amount_added'] . '"> ' . $row['pages'] . ' Page(s) / ' . $row['words'] . ' Words</option>';
                    } else {
                        echo '<option selected="selected" id="' . $row['idpw'] . 'nop" value="' . $row['idpw'] . '" title="' . $row['amount_added'] . '"> ' . $row['pages'] . ' Page(s) / ' . $row['words'] . ' Words</option>';
                    }
                    }
                    ?>

                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

javascript to effect the change and its not working

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function showPagesDiv(val) {

        if (val == 'Single Spaced') {
            document.getElementById('single').style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById('double').style.display = 'none';
        } else if(var == 'Double Spaced') {
            document.getElementById('single').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('double').style.display = 'block';
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: what is the error ?

Comment: @DhananjaiPai javascript is not working as in I want to start functioning when on select

Answer (score 0):

The answer is fairly easy to spot if you are looking in your console log. It gives you an error where it's breaking. Before that though, a couple points on your PHP:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-3 control-label">
        <!-- THERE IS NO NEED FOR PHP TO WRITE "Spacing" HERE -->
        <label for="spacing">Spacing<span class="star">&nbsp;*</span></label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-7">
        <select name="spacing" id="spacing" class="required" onchange="showPagesDiv(this.value);caltotal(this);">
            <option value="Double Spaced">Double Spaced</option>
            <option value="Single Spaced">Single Spaced</option>
        </select>
    </div>
```

In your section block, put your business logic in a function/class or at the top. You don't need to run the database twice since the calls are identical. Also, your `if` statement results in the same output as the `else` so either your html is wrong or your are misunderstanding what that script is doing:

```
<?php
# Start a string
$stropts = '';
# Call once
$query = $conn->query("SELECT  * FROM cww_avid_pages_words");

while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    # Perhaps it's the "selected" that you are trying to determine with if/else??
    $selected = (!empty($post['no_of_pages']) && ($post['no_of_pages'] ==  $row['idpw']))? ' selected="selected"' : '';
    # Assemble a string
    $stropts .= '<option'.$selected.' id="' . $row['idpw'] . 'nop" value="' . $row['idpw'] . '" title="' . $row['amount_added'] . '"> ' . $row['pages'] . ' Page(s) / ' . $row['words'] . ' Words</option>';
}
?>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-3 control-label">
        <label for="no_of_pages1">No of Pages or words<span class="star">&nbsp;*</span></label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-7">
        <div id="single" style="display: none;">
            <select name="no_of_pages1" id="no_of_pages1" onchange="caltotal()">
                <!-- Just echo the string here -->
                <?php echo $stropts ?>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div id="double" >
            <select name="no_of_pages2" id="no_of_pages2" onchange="caltotal()">
                <!-- Just echo the string here -->
                <?php echo $stropts ?>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now to the reason your JavaScript doesn't work—your `elseif` uses `var` instead of `val` so it errors out. Since you only have two possibilities, you can just make a ternary:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showPagesDiv(val) {
        document.getElementById('single').style.display = (val == 'Single Spaced')? 'block' : 'none';
        document.getElementById('double').style.display = (val == 'Single Spaced')? 'none' : 'block';
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am getting this error: **Notice: Undefined variable: post in** and when I change to `$_POST` I get this error **Notice: Undefined index: no_of_pages in**

Comment: Thanks, but I am getting this error: Notice: Undefined variable: post in and when I change to $_POST I get this error Notice: Undefined index: no_of_pages in

Comment: Then you need to first check if the `$post` (or `$_POST`, which ever it's supposed to be) is set. I just went off what you have. I will edit.